# Probability and Counting

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I have just picked up a text on discrete math and its been ages since I have done this so if anyone can show me with steps to correct my fault, that would be so great.
Repair facility has 25 failed keyboards, 6 of which have electrical defects and 19 which have mechanical defects.
(1) How many ways are there to randomly select 5 of these keyboards for a thorough inspection (order does not matter)? 25 choose 5
(2) IN how many ways can a sample of 5 keyboards be selected so that exactly tow have an electrical defect? (25 choose 5)/(6 choose 5)
(3) If a sample of 5 keyboards is randomly selected, what is the probability that at least 4 of these will have a mechanical defect? (5 choose 4)....?

Am I correct in my thinking logic or way off?

Answer (score 1):

For part 2, you need exactly two out of five so there are ${6 \choose 2}$ ways to do that leaving ${19\choose 3}$ for the remaining mechanically failed devices.  So in total there are ${6\choose 2}{19\choose 3}$ total ways.  Now for part three, think of what it means to say "at least" and use the same process.  So you need a sample with exactly 4 plus a sample with 5....
For cases where we are sampling without replacement, a hyper geometric distribution is used.  Say you want the probability of $K$ out $N$ successes with a sample size $n$.  Then the mass function looks like
$$P(X<k)=\sum_{i=0}^k{\frac{{K\choose i}{N-K \choose n-i}}{N \choose n}}$$

Comment: So the for 3, by "at least", would it be (5 choose 4)*(19 choose 1)? Or am I thinking of "at least" from the wrong perspective?

Comment: Wrong perspective...  You have 19 mechanically failed keyboards and 6 electrically failed keyboards.  So it should be ${6\choose 1}{19\choose 4}$, but at least means you can have 4 or 5 mechanically defective keyboards in your sample....  Can you finish it then?

Comment: So then if I am leaning in the right direction, would it be ((6 choose 1)*(19 choose 4))/(5 choose 4) ?

Comment: No...you have a new criterion to meet with the second case of 5 mechanically failed keyboards so that is ${19\choose 5}$.  Now you must sum the two cases.  This is counting , not probability so there should be no division in your method.  If you were looking for the probabilities of these cases you divide by ${25\choose 5}$.  This is sampling without replacement and calls for the hyper geometric distribution.

Comment: Okay so I saw part 3 calls for probability so you should have $\frac{{19\choose 4}{6\choose 1}+{19\choose 5}{6\choose 0}}{{25\choose 5}}$

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution